# Convert long-form dataframe of pairwise distances to distance matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, pairwise

I have a pandas dataframe of pairwise distances in the form of:

```
    SampleA   SampleB  Num_Differences
0  sample_1  sample_2                1
1  sample_1  sample_3                4
2  sample_2  sample_3                8
```

Note that there are no self-self comparisons (e.g., sample_1 vs sample_1 won't be represented). I would like to convert this table into a squareform distance matrix instead, like so:

```
            sample_1      sample_2  sample_3
sample_1                       1              4
sample_2         1                            8
sample_3         4             8
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do such a conversion in python? The problem is analogous to a previous question in R ([Converting pairwise distances into a distance matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492767/converting-pairwise-distances-into-a-distance-matrix-in-r)), but I don't know the corresponding python functions to use. The problem also appears to be the opposite of this question ([Convert a distance matrix to a list of pairwise distances in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573411/convert-a-distance-matrix-to-a-list-of-pairwise-distances-in-python)).

Some code to reproduce a dataframe in the form I'm using:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['sample_1', 'sample_2', 1],
                   ['sample_1', 'sample_3', 4],
                   ['sample_2', 'sample_3', 8]],
                  columns=['SampleA', 'SampleB', 'Num_Differences'])
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear. The link to the R question just appears to reshape the data, but you appear to be performing some reverse calculation to get 2 and 6 in the output from `1 4 8`. How do you know what resultants to use as there are potentially infinite subtraction operations which could produce distances of `1 4 8`.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I'm not actually wanting to do calculations, just to reshape the data from a 'molten'/long format into a matrix form. Perhaps I'm not using the correct terminology. I've also edited the question to fix up the numbers - they were left over from a more complex example I used originally - oops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reshape to square, and then make symmetrical by adding the transposed values:

```
# make unique, sorted, common index
idx = sorted(set(df['SampleA']).union(df['SampleB']))

# reshape
(df.pivot(index='SampleA', columns='SampleB', values='Num_Differences')
   .reindex(index=idx, columns=idx)
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   .pipe(lambda x: x+x.values.T)
 )
```

Alternatively, you can use ordered categorical indexes and keep NAs during reshaping with `pivot_table`. Then add the transposed values to make symmetrical:

```
cat = sorted(set(df['SampleA']).union(df['SampleB']))

(df.assign(SampleA=pd.Categorical(df['SampleA'],
                                  categories=cat,
                                  ordered=True),
           SampleB=pd.Categorical(df['SampleB'],
                                  categories=cat,
                                  ordered=True),
           )
    .pivot_table(index='SampleA',
                 columns='SampleB',
                 values='Num_Differences',
                 dropna=False, fill_value=0)
    .pipe(lambda x: x+x.values.T)
)
```

Output:

```
SampleB   sample_1  sample_2  sample_3
SampleA                               
sample_1         0         1         4
sample_2         1         0         8
sample_3         4         8         0
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Precompute an array of unique labels in the original pairwise distances:

```
idx = pd.concat([df['SampleA'], df['SampleB']]).unique()
idx.sort() 
idx

array(['sample_1', 'sample_2', 'sample_3'], dtype=object)
```

2. Pivot, then reindex both the index and columns to introduce zero values in the resulting intermediate DataFrame:

```
res = (df.pivot('SampleA', 'SampleB', 'Num_Differences')
         .reindex(index=idx, columns=idx)
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
res

SampleB   sample_1  sample_2  sample_3
SampleA                               
sample_1         0         1         4
sample_2         0         0         8
sample_3         0         0         0
```

3. Add the intermediate DataFrame to its own transpose to produce a symmetric pairwise distance matrix:

```
res += res.T
res

SampleB   sample_1  sample_2  sample_3
SampleA                               
sample_1         0         1         4
sample_2         1         0         8
sample_3         4         8         0
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. Is there a way to have the resulting matrix be symmetrical? (rather than zeroes in the bottom half)

Comment: Good point; I've edited my answer to produce a symmetric distance matrix. Looks like I end up with something similar to @mozway's excellent answer!

Answer (score 3):

We seem to be converting a weighted edgelist to an adjacency matrix. We can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) functions to make this conversion [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) to [`adjacency_matrix`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html):

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

# Create Graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df,
    source='SampleA',
    target='SampleB',
    edge_attr='Num_Differences'
)

# Build adjacency matrix
adjacency_df = pd.DataFrame(
    nx.adjacency_matrix(G, weight='Num_Differences').todense(),
    index=G.nodes,
    columns=G.nodes
)
```

`adjacency_df`:

```
          sample_1  sample_2  sample_3
sample_1         0         1         4
sample_2         1         0         8
sample_3         4         8         0
```

---

We can also fill the diagonal with [`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) if wanting NaN instead of 0s:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df,
    source='SampleA',
    target='SampleB',
    edge_attr='Num_Differences'
)

adjacency_df = pd.DataFrame(
    nx.adjacency_matrix(G, weight='Num_Differences').todense(),
    index=G.nodes,
    columns=G.nodes,
    dtype=float  # Compatible dtype with NaN is needed
)
# Overwrite the values on the diagonal
np.fill_diagonal(adjacency_df.values, np.NaN)
```

`adjacency_df`:

```
          sample_1  sample_2  sample_3
sample_1       NaN       1.0       4.0
sample_2       1.0       NaN       8.0
sample_3       4.0       8.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 pd.pivot_table(df, values='Num_Differences', index='Sample_A',
                columns='SampleB', aggfunc=max, fill_value=0)
```

Note that if you don't have more than one instance of the same pair of Sample_A, Sample_B, it doesn't matter much what aggfunc you use; you can use sum, max, min, mode, mean, etc. If having more than one is possible, you might want to consider how you want Pandas to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this shows the differences between samples, I'd prefer to have sample_1, sample_2, and sample_3 as the column and row names. This method shows sample_1 & sample_2 as row names, and sample_2 & sample_3 as columns names.